# How do I return a class array from one WPF window to another window?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, class

In a `WPF` window called from the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I have a class I defined with multiple elements.  I create an `array` of this class type.

In *FieldLengths.xaml.cs* I have:

```
public partial class FieldLengths : Window
{
    public FieldJustifyFill[] fjfFields = new FieldJustifyFill[0];
    public class FieldJustifyFill
    {
        public int ColumnNumber { get; set; }
        public bool RightJustify { get; set; }
        public bool LeftJustify { get; set; }
        public bool LeftZeroFill { get; set; }
        public bool RightZeroFill { get; set; }
    }
```

I load is this way:

```
try
        {
            dtFields = ((DataView)dtGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable();
            intNumFields = 0;

            for (int intRowCnt = 0; intRowCnt < dtFields.Rows.Count; intRowCnt++)
            {
                bool blnJustifyRight = Convert.ToBoolean(dtFields.Rows[intRowCnt][2]);
                bool blnJustifyLeft = Convert.ToBoolean(dtFields.Rows[intRowCnt][3]);
                bool blnLeftZeroFill = Convert.ToBoolean(dtFields.Rows[intRowCnt][4]);
                bool blnRightZeroFill = Convert.ToBoolean(dtFields.Rows[intRowCnt][5]);

                if (blnJustifyRight || blnJustifyLeft || blnLeftZeroFill || blnRightZeroFill)
                {

                    Array.Resize(ref fjfFields, intNumFields + 1);
                    fjfFields[intNumFields] = new FieldJustifyFill
                    {
                        ColumnNumber = intRowCnt,
                        RightJustify = blnJustifyRight,
                        LeftJustify = blnJustifyLeft,
                        LeftZeroFill = blnLeftZeroFill,
                        RightZeroFill = blnRightZeroFill
                    };

                    intNumFields += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strMsg;

            strMsg = "RefreshRowSize, error '" + ex.Message + "' has occurred.";
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
        }
```

*In MainWindow.xaml.cs* I have this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    FieldJustifyFillDest[] fjfFieldsDest = new FieldJustifyFillDest[0];
```

And in a routine I try to get the values from *FixedLengths.xaml.cs* like this:

```
FieldLengths flWin = new FieldLengths(strInputName, strFieldInfo, null, null, null, strMappingMetadata);
                flWin.Left = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.Left + 15;
                flWin.Top = desktopWorkArea.Top + 25;
                flWin.ShowDialog();

                if (flWin.blnFLCreateFile)
                {
                    string strPrgFileName;

                    Array.Resize(ref fjfFieldsDest, flWin.fjfFields.Length);

                    for (int i = 0; i < flWin.fjfFields.Length; i++)
                    {
                        int intColumnNumber = flWin.fjfFields[i].ColumnNumber;
                        bool blnRightJustify = flWin.fjfFields[i].RightJustify;
                        bool blnLeftJustify = flWin.fjfFields[i].LeftJustify;
                        bool blnLeftZeroFill = flWin.fjfFields[i].LeftZeroFill;
                        bool blnRightZeroFill = flWin.fjfFields[i].RightZeroFill;

                        fjfFieldsDest[i] = new FieldJustifyFillDest
                        {
                            ColumnNumber = intColumnNumber,
                            RightJustify = blnRightJustify,
                            LeftJustify = blnLeftJustify,
                            LeftZeroFill = blnLeftZeroFill,
                            RightZeroFill = blnRightZeroFill
                        };
                    }
```

The variable `intColumnNumber`, `blnRightJustify`, `blnLeftJustify`, `blnLeftZeroFill`, `blnRightZeroFill` have the correct values but when it is loaded into fjfFieldsDest[i] they are not correct.

How do I return the class array correctly?  I can not find a good example anywhere.

Comment: use debugger to see why values are not correct. put breakpoint before execution of code. press F11 to see what happens step by step.

Comment: You should check the generic `List<FieldJustifyFillDest>` instead of messing with arrays.

Comment: #Jeroen van Langen - Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: @Cass You could check over here: [`List<T>` Class - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, my code is working correctly as coded.  The debugger reordered the class elements alphabetically and I did not notice.  Sorry all.  However if the way I am coding it is not correct I welcome any feedback to code correctly.